# ERROR SEGURIDAD EN COLUMNAS SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, mssql

Un saludo estimada red, de vuelta por aca dado que tengo un problema en la seguridad de columnas en SQL SERVER 2014.

He creado la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE persons
  (PersonID int IDENTITY,
   FirstName varchar(100) NULL,
   Salary Numeric(18,2) NOT NULL,
   LastName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   Phone varchar(12) NULL,
   Email varchar(100) NULL);
```

Necesito que usuario "devUser" acceda a todas las columnas excepto a la columna Salary, que contiene información confidencial:

He utilizado el siguiente código que encontre en la documentación de SQL pero no me funciona, me sale error.

```
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::dbo.persons(PersonID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email) TO devUser;
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

```
Sub-entity lists (such as column or security expressions) cannot be specified for entity-level permissions.
```

No encuentro la solución si a alguien le ha pasado lo mismo por favor su apoyo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta dar permisos a las columnas individualmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dónde haya sido que has visto el ejemplo, no es de SQL Server.

En SQL Server la sintaxis para otorgar permisos sobre una tabla (y potencialmente las columnas de esta) es:

```sql
GRANT permiso ON tabla[(columnas)] TO usuario
```

Así, podrías otorgar los permisos sobre la tabla que mencionas, así:

```sql
grant select on dbo.persons(PersonId, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email) to devUser;
go
```

Y otro ejemplo:

```sql
grant update on dbo.persons(FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email) to devUser;
go
```

Y para quitar el permiso de selección sobre una columna:

```
revoke select on dbo.persons(Email) to devUser;
go
```

Comment: está muy interesante dar permisos a las columnas por usuario, solo tendría que documentarlo bien, por si luego agregan columnas, que no se vuelvan locos sin saber porque no se ven.
También sería una opción hacer una vista y  ahí excluir esa columna y dar permisos sobre la vista y no sobre la tabla.

Comment: @jachguate muy buen aporte me ayudo con la sintaxis, sabes me funciona bien con select y update, pero no con insert y delete, no encuentro el motivo, por favor si encuentran alguna info al respecto compartir, pero lo que necesitaba me funciono muy bien. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @DAES, pienso que es correcto que con insert y con delete no se pueda dar _permisos por columnas_. No tendría sentido. Como mencionó MrDonPh0x hace un par de comentarios, en el caso del insert, podrías crear una vista y darle permisos sobre la vista. Para que el insert funcione, debiera incluir todas las columnas que son _not null_ y no tienen un valor default. De otra manera, siempre fallará. Y bueno, con el delete, no podes borrar solo algunas columnas de un registro. Siempre borras el registro completo.

Comment: @jachguate y MrDonPh0x muchas gracias por su ayuda y comentarios.